# Vector notation for the slope of a line using simple regression

Tags: vectors, linear-regression

How can the equation for the slope of a line (using simple regression) be represented using vector notation (i.e. vectorized)?

$$\text{slope} = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}) }{ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2} $$

I came across [this representation in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538936/4484576) on Stack Overflow:

$$\text{slope} = \frac{\left\langle {x \circ y} \right\rangle - \left\langle {x} \right\rangle \left\langle {y} \right\rangle}{\left\langle {x^2} \right\rangle - \left\langle {x} \right\rangle^2}$$

Where $\circ$ is element-wise multiplication (Hadamard product) and $\left\langle {} \right\rangle$ denotes the mean.

I can't figure out how to derive the vector representation from the original definition based on summations.

I'm curious if there is a more elegant (and intuitive) representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an elegant solution:

$$X = x - \bar{x}$$
$$Y = y - \bar{y}$$

Where $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are vectors where each element is the mean of $x$ and $y$, respectively.

$$\text{slope} = \frac{ X \bullet Y }{ X \bullet X} $$

(h/t to the anonymous teacher at Waterloo-Oxford high school!)